# weightSum not splitting screen properly in android

Tags: android, android-layout

This is my layout file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="2">       

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/mainText"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
                android:text="Default Text"
                android:textSize="24dip" />


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/detailsText"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
                android:text="Default Text"

                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />


        </LinearLayout>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="Hot"
            />

    </LinearLayout>
```

I want to split the screen width into two parts. First part will have 2 texts (second below first one) and second split part have a button.

The above layout splits the screen into 3 parts. I don't understand why?

can anyone help me on this?
i want to display two text second below the first one

Comment: Both `LinearLayout` and `Button` should occupy same space horizontally on the screen? Or you can use `RelativeLayout` for ease.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one  with proof

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="2">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_weight="1">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/mainText"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
                    android:text="Default Text"
                    android:textSize="24dip" />


                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/detailsText"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
                    android:layout_weight="0.5"
                    android:text="Default Text" />
            </LinearLayout>


                <Button
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
 android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:text="Hot" />
            </LinearLayout>


    </RelativeLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks and add this attribute in button  android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" so it's look batter

Answer (score 2):

Your `android:layout_width` attribute should be 0dp

Set -

```
android:layout_width="0dp"
```

for the inner `LinearLayout` and the `Button`

The thing is when you want to achieve ratio then you don't set that particular dimension (width or height) to match parent. Rather set it to 0dp so that Android can handle it for you automatically.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="2">



        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/mainText"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
                android:text="Default Text"
                android:textSize="24dip" />


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/detailsText"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
                android:text="Default Text"

                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />


        </LinearLayout>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="Hot"
            />



    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

In fact this layout exactly splitting 2 part. But maybe because of position of your `Button`, you were confussed. I suggest you to set your `layout_height` of root layout to `wrap_content`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:orientation="horizontal"
          android:weightSum="2">



<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/mainText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
        android:text="Default Text"
        android:textSize="24dip" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/detailsText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
        android:text="Default Text"

        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />


</LinearLayout>

<Button
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:text="Hot"
    />
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out following code

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="center"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:weightSum="2" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/mainText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
        android:text="Default Text"
        android:textSize="24dip" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/detailsText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
        android:text="Default Text" />
</LinearLayout>

<Button
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="Hot" />

</LinearLayout>
```

in this code am make the layout_width of the child view of main parent int 0dp

and if you need to make it in to the center give garvity property of main parent in "center"